# ESXi Windows Server 2003 Guest 32-bit Installation gets stuck on blue Starting Windows screen?

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-player, 32-bit

I'm trying to install Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition 32-bit as a guest on ESXi 5.1 for testing purposes; but when I try to install it, it gets stuck on the blue `Starting Windows` screen and the CPU usage on the VM CPU jumps to 50% and it kind of sits there.

Is it possible to install this on VM Ware Player and then export from there and import it into the ESXi?

Comment: Check your disk controleer on the vm setup .

Comment: Yes it's possible, you can use vmware converter. It's free and easy to use.

Comment: I have multiple 2k3 32bit VMs running OK on ESXi 5.1.  There's some other problem here, exporting from Player isn't the right path...